# How do setup msword document to have different print section?

Tags: ms-word

I want to setup a word document which has several chapters. For a particular set of readers (eg my boss), I want to only print to pdf chap 1-5 and for another set of readers (eg my customers), I want to print to pdf out chap 6-10.

Is this possible with MS-word?

edit: elaboration.

Comment: Please elaborate. When you say print you mean printing on screen or printing on a printer machine or a pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need a way to get who is the user and determine to which part of the document he has access (you can use the WNetGetUser API in the microsoft Mpr.dll), then you can show and hide the different sections of the document. For the second part the easiest way is to create bookmarks for the different chapters of your document and hide/show them using:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bookmark01").Range.Font.Hidden = True 'to hide text
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bookmark01").Range.Font.Hidden = False 'to show text
```

Comment: Thanks. will that update all the fields in the document eg chapter numbering, table of contents.